# Clean URLs Nginx Rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

After searching the interweb for hours and none of the "guides" working I turn to you guys and girls for help.

I am attempting to clean all my urls for all files in any directory so www.foo.com/foo.php becomes www.foo.com/foo.

Also I want to tidy up requests such as www.foo.com/foo.php?foo=foo to www.foo.com/foo/foo

Here is my current failed attempt:

```
    server {
    # Change these settings to match your machine
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # Everything below here doesn't need to be changed
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

    root /var/www/example.com;
     try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

            # The next two lines should go in your fastcgi_params
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;

   }
location /phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               root /usr/share/;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
       location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
               root /usr/share/;
       }
       }
       location /phpMyAdmin {
       rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
       }
       }
```

It works but I can still access the old .php url aswell which as far as im aware is bad for SEO? as its duplicate content?

Thanks in Advance
Danny